# Lubuntu either fails to install grub or fails to boot after what seems to be successfull instalation

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

I am trying to install lubuntu on my Asus netbook. Before I reach installation type, I see warning:

> Force UEFI Installation? This machines's firmware has started this
>   installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there maybe existing
>   operating systems already installed using BIOS compatibility mode, If
>   you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,it might be difficult to
>   reboot into any BIOS-mode operating system.

Then if I try to go "Erase disk and install Lubuntu", it fails to install grub:

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/.
>   Without the grub boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

If I chose "Something else", create partitions: ext4 mounted in '/', swap and efi, and chose efi to install boot loader there, installation seems to finish successfully.

But when I turn the computer on again, only bios appears and I don't see lubuntu in booting options.

Failure to install grub happens also when I chose the whole disk (/dev/mmcblk0, while efi is /dev/mmcblk0p1) as a "device for boot loader installation".

On the other hand, can I correctly setup grub from terminal, considering the fact that I have a fully functioning system until I restart the computer?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Go into your BIOS and enable CSM and then boot the Ubuntu install media  in legacy/MBR mode

Comment: Is grub really installed to ESP - efi system partition, but your Asus is not booting it? Can you directly boot from UEFI menu often f10 or f12?

Answer (score 0):

If your UEFI-set up netbook does not want to boot, you can try to solve the problem afterwards while booting into a [SystemRescueImage](http://mindbytez.com/oss) and there trying as root with chroot, grub-install and update-grub to install and configure your grub2. See https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall how to do that.

Alternatively you can try to disable SecureBoot: search for "Disabling SecureBoot in the BIOS" in your search engine (with the quotes).

There is also a Boot-Repair available, which might help: Search for "boot repair ubuntu" in your search engine (without the quotes).